# Dealing with mixed format date-time data in R

Tags: r, datetime

I am reading data into R using `read_excel`. One of the columns `date_time` has a mixed format and is read in as a character vector. Here is a sample of the rows.

```
date_time <- c(
  45144.4762962963,
  45144.475138888891,
  "14-08-2023 10:38:54 AM",
  "14-08-2023 10:37:03 AM",
  "24-05-2023 9:29:44 AM",
  "24-05-2023 9:27:18 AM",
  45113.462395833332,
  45113.461261574077,
  "15-05-2023 1:47:12 PM",
  44988.399664351855
)

data <- tibble(date_time)
```

How can I convert this into a consistent `dttm` object? I think I could do this by editing the excel file that I'm reading in (the numbers starting with the digit 4 is the way excel stores dates), but since this will be an ongoing issue I'd like to find a way to do this within R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Steps:

1. Check if the value is just digits and periods (technically, this would match bad examples (e.g. "........10."), but let's just leave that aside for the moment
2. If it matches, then turn it into a numeric, then into a date, and then into a datetime
3. If not, then just parse it using the format string from as_datetime()

```
library(tidyverse)
data |> 
   mutate(cleaned = as_datetime(ifelse(grepl("^[0-9\\.]+$", date_time), 
                                       as.numeric(date_time) |> as_date(origin = "1899-12-30") |> as_datetime(), 
                                       as_datetime(date_time, format = "%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   date_time              cleaned            
   <chr>                  <dttm>             
 1 45144.4762962963       2023-08-06 11:25:52
 2 45144.4751388889       2023-08-06 11:24:12
 3 14-08-2023 10:38:54 AM 2023-08-14 10:38:54
 4 14-08-2023 10:37:03 AM 2023-08-14 10:37:03
 5 24-05-2023 9:29:44 AM  2023-05-24 09:29:44
 6 24-05-2023 9:27:18 AM  2023-05-24 09:27:18
 7 45113.4623958333       2023-07-06 11:05:50
 8 45113.4612615741       2023-07-06 11:04:13
 9 15-05-2023 1:47:12 PM  2023-05-15 13:47:12
10 44988.3996643519       2023-03-03 09:35:31
```

Notes:

1. It seems like dplyr doesn't pick up on the fact that we want a datetime column unless I put it the third as_datetime() at the base of the ifelse() function call. It doesn't really do anything though. Quite frustrating!
2. You'll get some warnings doing this. This is because it's as if we have processed the entire column in two different ways, and the ifelse decides which value we select from. So (for example) we are only selecting the `as.numeric` one from the rows where the value is actually a number as a string, but as.numeric is still trying to convert (for example) "14-08-2023 10:38:54 AM" into a number, and then failing, which is where we get the warning.

Comment: Thanks! I get a warning message but it seems to work great and there's no NAs introduced. Any idea why?
`Warning message:
There were 2 warnings in `mutate()`.
The first warning was:
ℹ In argument: `cleaned = as_datetime(...)`.
Caused by warning in `as_date()`:
! NAs introduced by coercion
ℹ Run dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings() to see the 1 remaining warning. `

Comment: @Mark I should have explained that! Gonna add a comment now

Comment: thank you! I'm wondering if you could please take a look at another question which is an extension of this one. I posted a new question since I thought your existing answer might still be helpful to others. I think I need to write an ifelse statement that switches mm and dd if the dd is less than 12, but not really sure how to implement this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77187186/dealing-with-incorrectly-parsed-date-time-data-in-r

Answer (score 0):

If you use the function `readxl::read_excel()`, you can specify the types of the columns you want to read. In your case, you should write

```
readxl::read_excel(path_file, col_types = "date")
```

Please consult the [section about the dates](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/cell-and-column-types.html#date-column) of the {readxl} vignette.
Have a look at the {readxl} excel file example with `browseURL(readxl::readxl_example("type-me.xlsx"))` and you will see that there is also a mix of date formats.

Here is the example provided in the cited section of the {readxl} vignette:

```
df <- readxl::read_excel(readxl::readxl_example("type-me.xlsx"),
  sheet = "date_coercion",
  col_types = c("date", "text")
)
#> Warning: Expecting date in A5 / R5C1: got boolean
#> Warning: Expecting date in A6 / R6C1: got 'cabbage'
#> Warning: Coercing numeric to date in A7 / R7C1
#> Warning: Coercing numeric to date in A8 / R8C1
print(df, n = Inf)
#> # A tibble: 7 × 2
#>   `maybe a datetime?` explanation           
#>   <dttm>              <chr>                 
#> 1 NA                  "empty"               
#> 2 2016-05-23 00:00:00 "date only format"    
#> 3 2016-04-28 11:30:00 "date and time format"
#> 4 NA                  "boolean true"        
#> 5 NA                  "\"cabbage\""         
#> 6 1904-01-05 07:12:00 "4.3 (numeric)"       
#> 7 2012-01-02 00:00:00 "another numeric"
```