# Dealing with incorrectly parsed date-time data in R

Tags: r, excel, date, lubridate

I am reading data into R from Excel using `read_excel`. One of the columns `date_time` has a mixed format and is read in as a character vector. Here is a sample of the rows.

```
date_time <- c(
  45144.4762962963,
  45144.475138888891,
  "14-08-2023 10:38:54 AM",
  "14-08-2023 10:37:03 AM",
  "24-05-2023 9:29:44 AM",
  "24-05-2023 9:27:18 AM",
  45113.462395833332,
  45113.461261574077,
  "15-05-2023 1:47:12 PM",
  44988.399664351855
)

data <- tibble(date_time)
```

It appears the reason for the mixed-format is that when the data was parsed into the Excel table initially, it was expecting the format **mm-dd**-yyyy hh:mm:ss but the actual data was **dd-mm** (switched). The outcome is that where the first digits were greater than 12, it was parsed into Excel as a text variable (e.g. row 3 of `data`). However when the date was ambiguous, it was parsed in Excel's date format with the date and month incorrectly switched (e.g. row 1 of `data` should be 8 Jun 2023 11:25:52 AM, not 6 Aug 2023).

How can I convert this into a consistent `dttm` object with the correct dates? I think I could do this by editing the Excel file that I'm reading in, but since this will be an ongoing issue I'd like to find a way to do this within R.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52319606/3358272 shows how to work with multiple candidate formats when converting dates, it can easily be adapted to work here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70304571/3358272 is similar but with `POSIXt` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be a tidier way to do it, but the following code would do the work
for your combination of formats.

First converting the easy one with `parse_date_time`, and then converting the numeric to date time and reading the date in the right order.

```
data <- tibble(date_time) |>
  mutate(
    new_date_time1 = parse_date_time(
      date_time,
      orders = c("%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p"),
      tz = "UTC"
    ),
    new_date_time2 = parse_date_time(
      as.character(
        as.POSIXct(
          as.Date(
            as.numeric(date_time),
              origin =
                "1899-12-30")
    )),
    orders = c("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"))) |>
  transmute(fixed_date_time = if_else(is.na(new_date_time1),
                                      new_date_time2,
                                      new_date_time1))

# A tibble: 10 × 1
#    fixed_date_time    
#    <dttm>             
#  1 2023-06-08 11:25:52
#  2 2023-06-08 11:24:12
#  3 2023-08-14 10:38:54
#  4 2023-08-14 10:37:03
#  5 2023-05-24 09:29:44
#  6 2023-05-24 09:27:18
#  7 2023-06-07 11:05:50
#  8 2023-06-07 11:04:13
#  9 2023-05-15 13:47:12
# 10 2023-03-03 09:35:31
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create two functions. The first one is to convert the numeric dates to an R date time object:

```r
get_date_from_numeric <- function(date, origin = "1899-12-30") {
    date_day_month_switched <- as.POSIXct(origin, tz = "UTC") +
        as.difftime(as.numeric(date), units = "days")
    # Switch month and day
    strptime(date_day_month_switched, "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
}
```

See [here](https://epirhandbook.com/en/working-with-dates.html) for why Excel's origin is 30th December 1899 (on Windows).

We also create a function to convert the character dates:

```
get_date_from_string  <- function(date) {
    strptime(date, "%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz = "UTC")
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39400404/12545041) for the meaning of the [`strptime()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) symbols.

The string function will return `NA` for the numeric dates, and vice versa. This means we can [`coalesce()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/coalesce.html) the results:

```r
library(dplyr)

data |>
    mutate(
        numeric_date = get_date_from_numeric(date_time),
        string_date = get_date_from_string(date_time),
        clean_date = coalesce(numeric_date, string_date)
    ) |>
    select(-numeric_date, -string_date)

# # A tibble: 10 × 2
#    date_time              clean_date
#    <chr>                  <dttm>
#  1 45144.4762962963       2023-06-08 11:25:52
#  2 45144.4751388889       2023-06-08 11:24:12
#  3 14-08-2023 10:38:54 AM 2023-08-14 10:38:54
#  4 14-08-2023 10:37:03 AM 2023-08-14 10:37:03
#  5 24-05-2023 9:29:44 AM  2023-05-24 09:29:44
#  6 24-05-2023 9:27:18 AM  2023-05-24 09:27:18
#  7 45113.4623958333       2023-06-07 11:05:50
#  8 45113.4612615741       2023-06-07 11:04:13
#  9 15-05-2023 1:47:12 PM  2023-05-15 13:47:12
# 10 44988.3996643519       2023-03-03 09:35:31
```

Note: you will get an `NAs introduced by coercion` warning. That's by design - we expect `NA` for the invalid format which is why we can `coalesce()`.

Comment: Thanks @SamR! This works except I also needed to switch the date/month for the `get_date_from_numeric` function. Perhaps I didn't make this clear in my initial question which I have tried to clarify (although the other solution works so I'm no longer in need of help, thanks)

Comment: @Mark oops I thought I had dealt with that! As you say you've already got an answer but nevertheless I've fixed it now.